# Oracle - Count Between Min and Next Record Calendar

Tags: sql, oracle, date, calendar

I am trying to find a way to get the next record from a Calendar where the Next Option is a 2. I ultimately am trying to get a count of the Number of Days between the Min date and the Next Date that fits my criteria. I am able to pull up all Dates with the Opt of 2, but am not able to either skip the Min and return the Next Date, or gather a count between the two dates. Is there anyway this is possible. The code I have to this point is:

```
SELECT (B.eff/1440 +  TO_DATE('01/01/1970', 'mm/dd/yyyy')) AS OPEN_DATE,(B.eff/1440),                (B.eff/1440)+1 , OPT
FROM CALDATA B
where B.cal = 'SHIP_543_TO_305'
AND B.OPT = '2'
ORDER BY OPEN_DATE
```

It brings back all Dates with an Opt of 2, but I haven't been able to get any sql to work that will not bring back the Min, or give me a count between Dates.

This is an example of what the data looks like

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/00878/1/0

My endgame in this is that if tomorrow is my 'ShipDate', then today is my 'OrderDate' and I need to take all orders that are between Today and my next 'ShipDate'. This is where I am starting.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Could you provide sample data and expected result?

Comment: So the data I get is OPEN_DATE (7/2/2013,7/5/2013) EFF/1440 (15888,15891) EFF/1440 +1 (15889,15892) OPT (2,2). The data I am getting back is expected for the sql I am using. However, I can't figure out how to get it to give me the number of days between the Min (in this case 7/2/2013) and the Next Date (7/5/2013). I am needing this to populate another field for a different script.

Comment: What I meant is for you to edit your original question, provide table structure with some values and expected result, best if you would set up an example on www.sqlfiddle.com

Comment: Ahh, ok. Sorry about that. I inserted a sqlfiddle with my table structure. Hopefully it makes more sense.